# The best approach to get the element in Java

Tags: java, selenium, testing, data-structures, ui-automation

There is an e-commerce site. Every day when they run the program, it has to return the featured product. Featured product is the most sold product of the day. In case if there are two or more products are identified as featured products then the method should sort them alphabetically and then return the last item.

For example

```java
input_Products = [”redpencil”, “greenpencil”, “redpencil”, “yellowpencil”, “yellowpencil”]
```

For the given input the output should be returned as `yellowpencil`.

Below is my approach to the method called `getFeaturedProduct()` is below

```java
public static String getFeaturedProduct(List<String> items) {
   int length = items.size();
   Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

   for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
   {
       String prod = items.get(i);
       if(map.containsKey(prod))
       {
           map.put(prod, map.get(prod)+1);
       }
       else
           map.put(prod, 1);
   }

   int maxPurchasedItem = Collections.max(map.values());
   System.out.println("Max Purchased Item : " + maxPurchasedItem);

   List<String> prodNames = new ArrayList<>();
   for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry :map.entrySet())
   {
       if(entry.getValue() == maxPurchasedItem)
       {
           prodNames.add(entry.getKey());
       }
   }

   Collections.sort(prodNames);
   System.out.println("the featured item is : "+ prodNames.get(prodNames.size()-1));
   return prodNames.get(prodNames.size()-1);
}
```

Could you please tell me is this the best approach to proceed? What is the time complexity of this approach?

Comment: Your code works as you require. What is indeed your question?

Comment: What do you think the time complexity is?

Comment: @JoãoDias: I am at the beginning of understanding data structures and their time complexity.  This question was asked in my interview when I mention this way of approach they asked me the time complexity of this code?  I need help understanding the time complexity of this code or the best solution for this question.

Answer (score 0):

It has an `O(n)` time complexity, which is basically defined by the loop `for(int i=0; i<length; i++)`. You can read more about this at the following online resources:

- https://www.baeldung.com/java-algorithm-complexity
- https://adrianmejia.com/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm-code-big-o-notation/

Comment: Thanks for your input. Definitely will go through the documents

Comment: You are welcome. If it is and my answer helped you consider upvoting it. Thanks! ;)